# Javascript array sorting with alphanumeric 2nd string

Tags: javascript

I want to sort the multiple elements in an array. The elements are like 123_test_site, 456_rit_kol, 65_aws_folder ....... output should be on the basis of 1st string starting character as 65_aws_folder,456_rit_kol,123_test_site. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Con you post a [mcve] with JavaScript? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that might help you. My solution is like this:

```
const arr=['456_rit_kol', '65_aws_folder', '123_test_site',]; 

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    let input1 = a.substring(a.indexOf('_'));
    let input2 = b.substring(b.indexOf('_'));
    if(input1 < input2){
        return -1;
    }else{
        if(input1 < input2){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The first `else` and the outer `if` have the same condition: `input1 < input2`. Quite possibly a typo.